# problem to create-react-app by using npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: reactjs

D:\Projects\MY PRACTICE\my-app>npm run start
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> my-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'react'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
  at Object. (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:43:31)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
  at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js'
  ]
  }

D:\Projects\MY PRACTICE\my-app>

Comment: When are you getting error. While npx create-react-app my-app or npm run start ?

Comment: I got this error from try to install yarn and npm both. Now I uninstall yarn still got this same problem

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning that your command works, but it might not work in the future.

Try this command to install react with global dependency:

```
npm install --location=global create-react-app
```

Comment: after Install the command still I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error over and over again. How to solve this issue

D:\Projects\MY PRACTICE>npx create-react-app my-try05
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

Creating a new React app in D:\Projects\MY PRACTICE\my-try05.

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

changed 1396 packages in 2m

203 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
Missing dependencies in package.json

D:\Projects\MY PRACTICE>